# How to pass parameters to controller in object oriented style

Tags: objective-c, oop, object-oriented-analysis

When a photo is clicked I check It's category and call a http request function and 
configure its parameters according to photos category. Here is a simplified code:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Item *item = (Item *) [self.recentItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ( [item.Type  isEqual: @"typeA"] ) {
         connectionProperties.P1 = "A1"
         connectionProperties.P2 = "A2"
    }
    else if ( [item.Type  isEqual: @"typeB"] ){
         connectionProperties.P1 = "B1"
         connectionProperties.P3 = "B2"
         connectionProperties.P4 = "B3"
    }
 }

   albumDataController = [[AlbumDataController alloc] initWithConnectionProperty:connectionProperties andCommunicator:self.comm];


[albumDataController fetchItemsForCategory:category
            ItemsSuccess:^(Album *album) {

                photos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:album.photos];

                PhotoViewController *photoViewController = [[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotos:photos];


                [self presentViewController: photoViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


            }

}
```

I know this is not object oriented way.  How should I realize this in object oriented way.

Answer (score 1):

The object-oriented approach would be to have subclasses of `Item` create their own connection properties (or better yet have an `Item` protocol since Objective-C doesn't have abstract methods).

**Example:**

```
@interface Item : NSObject
- (ConnectionProperties *)connectionProperties;
@end

@implementation Item

- (ConnectionProperties *)connectionProperties
{
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}

@end

@interface ItemA : Item
@end

@implementation ItemA

- (ConnectionProperties *)connectionProperties
{
    ConnectionProperties *connectionProperties = [[ConnectionProperties alloc] init];
    connectionProperties.P1 = "A1";
    connectionProperties.P2 = "A2";
    return connectionProperties;
}

@end

@interface ItemB : Item
@end

@implementation ItemB

- (ConnectionProperties *)connectionProperties
{
    ConnectionProperties *connectionProperties = [[ConnectionProperties alloc] init]; 
    connectionProperties.P1 = "B1"
    connectionProperties.P3 = "B2"
    connectionProperties.P4 = "B3"
    return connectionProperties;
}

@end
```

This way your code doesn't need to know the internals of items:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Item *item = (Item *) [self.recentItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    albumDataController = [[AlbumDataController alloc] initWithConnectionProperty:item.connectionProperties andCommunicator:self.comm];
```

Using a protocol would be similar:

```
@protocol Item <NSObject>
- (ConnectionProperties *)connectionProperties;
...
@end
```

Comment: I'll take for granted that `Item` already exists for the purpose of representing something.  As such, making each item type implement `connectionProperties` violates the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), [it decreases cohesion and it increases coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)).  As such, adapters would be more suitable, together with a factory that looks up a table where an adapter class can be registered or configured (vs. hard-coded) for an item class and creates such adapter.

Comment: @PauloMadeira But fact that `Item` has a type property and represents multiple kinds of things means it does not have a single responsibility.  Item is currently responsible for representing an object and how to get it (by someone else recognizing the item type and doing something).  I'm not adding a responsibility here.  I'm just swapping `Item.Type` for `Item.connectionProperties`.  Creating an adapter just moves this conditional smell somewhere else.

Comment: That's the dark path to overloaded objects.  "Just" moving the conditional smell is 50% of what makes it OO (factory), another 30% being the adapter itself (a separate class for a separate purpose, i.e. HTTP requests) and the final 20% is the ability to (un)register/configure adapters for classes, perhaps even make the association automatic by default i.e. if nothing is registered/configured e.g. by class name.

Comment: I guess we're both making assumptions about what Item is and does, how complex the overall system is, etc.  Not every tool will be right for every circumstance.